# Rails: Action cable stream_from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I try to stream the current_user.id, but I get only id = 1...

```
class NotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "notification:#{current_user.id}"
  end
end


Console Log

NotificationsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
NotificationsChannel is streaming from notification:1
```

The user has id = 56 but insted getting notification:56, I get notification:1

How can I solve it? Thank you

Comment: Add the code for how you're defining the current user.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I figured out... Is active admin the problem. The stream get the admin user with id = 1.